# Out of heap memory for XSSF java read excel file

Tags: java, excel, xlsx, xls, xssf

Excel allows around 65K records in a .xls file.
For more data, I am using .xlsx file .
I used HSSF previously and now using XSSF for reading this xlsx in java.
Now my question is, when I save data in .xls (<65K ) and run with HSSF I am able to
and when storing it in .xlsx and reading with XSSF(<65K still) my program throws out of heap memory.
Want to know if it's even possible because I verified it multiple times.
What I also observed the same data as xls has file size 19MB and as xlsx as 16MB
still reading xls doesn't throw memory issue but xlsx does.
Any idea how to solve it 
ans what might be the reason causing this behaviour.
I have tried changing multiple sizes from 1024M to 4096M
It either fails to create a VM with given size or throws out of heap space.
Why is it specifically for xlsx read and not when xls read.

Comment: JVM args: **-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

Comment: *"Any idea how to solve it"* Add more memory to the JVM, e.g. as showed by Aniket Sahrawat in that first comment.

Comment: still get out of heap for 1024m

Comment: If you have limited memory, and a relatively large XLSX file, you can consider using SAX to parse the file. It depends on what you need to do with the file, of course - but this will allow you to scan the entire file with a relatively small memory footprint, and access its data. If this is of interest, I can provide more info - and you can read about it [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) also.